# Covariance/Contravariance Conundrum when using generic interface constraints

Tags: c#, generics, interface, covariance, contravariance

```
    public interface IShape{}

    public class Rectangle : IShape{}

    public class Base{}

    public class Derived : Base{}

    public interface IFoo<out T, in U>
        where T : IShape
        where U : Base
    {
        T Convert(U myType);
    }

    public class MyFoo : IFoo<Rectangle, Derived>
    {
        public Rectangle Convert(Derived myType)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }    

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IFoo<IShape, Base> hmm = new MyFoo();
        }
    }
```

Given the above code, the compiler is unable to determine how to assign the type `MyFoo` to `IFoo<IShape, Base>`, presumably because `U` is set as an out meaning that it can accept less derived. However, `Derived` is, well, more derived than `Base`, so generates a compiler error.

This example is contrived but the implementation we are dealing with is one in which `MyFoo` would be returned from a factory.

Although `U` is used as a parameter, it is also an output when trying to assign it to the generic interface but I am unable to use the `out` keyword here. How could we work around this?

Comment: So far you've only stated *facts*. You've got this code, you're having problems with it, you're getting a compiler error; that sounds like every day at my job too! Is there a *question* you wanted to ask us?

Comment: Hehe, fair point :)  I guess I wanted some workaround ideas and didn't explicitly ask for them :p

Answer (score 1):

Your IFoo interface seems to be wrong in this usage, it should be:

```
public interface IFoo<out T, **out** U>
```

With `U` being out. Remember that an `out` generic type parameter means that it can vary "outwards". That is, you can widen the type implicitly to a wider type. `In`, though, means that you can implicitly narrow the type "inwards" to a more specific type. These are just rough analogies, of course.

So in the case of the assignment of `hmm`, you are are implicitly trying to widen the interface generic type parameter for `U` from `Derived` to `Base`, but the interface declares it to be narrowing (`in`):

```
IFoo<IShape, Base> hmm = new MyFoo();
```

So it can't make the implicit conversion. If you really want to be able to widen this interface implicitly, the second type argument should be `out` instead of `in`.

Update: after your comments, I see that the big dilemma is that you want it to be both in and out, which isn't really possible  Since it's a contravariant input, you can't assign the interface covariantly to `IFoo<IShape, Base>`, unfortunately.

You either need to code around the fact you can't assign to `IFoo<IShape,Base>` or what you could do is create Foo as:

`public class MyFoo : IFoo<Rectangle, Base>`

And then cast to `Rectangle` inside the implementation. The main thing is you can't have both covariance and contravariance on the same type parameter.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Indeed, that would make sense.  However, as U is an input for a method changing it to out yields; Invalid variance: The type parameter 'U' must be contravariantly valid on 'ConsoleApplication3.IFoo<T,U>.Convert(U)'. 'U' is covariant.

Comment: Good point on that, then the answer would be you can't do it.  You can't have a type be both covariant and contravariant.  So you'd have to assign hmm to be an IFoo<IShape, Derived>

Comment: DO you mean cast to `Derived` inside the implemenation?

Answer (score 0):

Something that can convert a Base into a Rectangle will also turn a Derived into an IShape.  Something that can convert a Derived into a Rectangle, however, may not be able to do anything useful with a Base.  You correctly identified that the covariance specifier for your second parameter needs to be "in", but are then trying to use the covariance in the way opposite what it actually supports.

Comment: When you state "...may not be able to do anything useful with a Base", the interface has a constraint that `U` has to be at least of ttype `Base` so I would expect anything that implements interface IFoo to know how to deal with `Base`.

Comment: Something that can accept a base type as a parameter can accept a derived type, but the reverse is not true.  Something that knows how to handle every ToyotaTercel may not know how to deal with a FordTaurus, even though both ToyotaTercel and FordTaurus derive from Car.  Your MyFoo class accepts objects of type Derived.  It could also accept objects of sub-derived types.  It can't deal with objects of type Base.